# How do I customize the Forms Authentication cookie name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have 2 websites running on localhost in different ports. As browsers do not differentiate port numbers when sending cookies, my forms authentication ticket from one site is being sent to the other

How do I solve this? I thought that a good solution would be to change the forms authentication ticket or one of the websites but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="{WhateverCookieNameYouWant}" loginUrl="LogOn.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Is the leading dot a requirement? I was trying to find information about it, and didn't have much luck. I did find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5373980/88709) and went through its answers, but I have to admit I'm more confused than before :|

Comment: I am not sure.  I read that post  you linked and now I am more confused then before as well :O

Comment: @DustinHodges I've been struggling with for ages, thanks for this answer!!

Comment: The `.` in the name is not required.

Comment: @SerjSagan removed dot . . . three years later.  Thanks