# Why does the default ASP.NET Forms Authentication Cookie have a leading period in it's default name => ".ASPXAUTH"

Tags: .net, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

the default [ASP.NET Forms Authentication cookie sets it's name as "**.ASPXAUTH**"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiename.aspx). Notice the first character is a **period**? Is there a particular reason for this? Like, does this have an impact on domain names or subdomains for the target domain.

Or is it purely some random thing an MS dev person came up with (maybe to help out the ordering of the cookies, when they were debugging or something .. as text with periods prolly get listed before other strings)?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but I was about to post the same question and found this one. I clarified the correct answer (which is not the accepted answer). After an hour of research I was not able to find anything stating why Msft chose ".ASPXAUTH" so my guess is it is totally arbitrary dev decision. I would have preferred they call it something like "CHANGEME", but oh well.. Maybe somebody has a friend who works at Msft and knows the lore of choosing this particular value.

Comment: I reckon it's so it shows up first in the cookie list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was unable to find the "two dots" requirement that sajoshi mentioned, but I did find this on the HTTP specification rfc2109.

> Domain=domain
>         Optional.  The Domain attribute specifies the domain for which the
>         cookie is valid.  An explicitly specified domain must always start
>         with a dot.

### http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109

The section is **4.2.2 Set-Cookie Syntax**.  I did not know there was a dot requirement at all before sajoshi's post, so I looked it up, but it seems that he was half right.  If someone gives it a closer reading and can point out anything I've missed, please do.

### Update

I **did** find in section 4.3.3 that

> The request-host is a FQDN (not IP address) and has the form HD, where D is the value of the Domain attribute, and H is a string that contains one or more dots.

(FQDN is a Fully Qualified Domain Name)

> A Set-Cookie from request-host y.x.foo.com for Domain=.foo.com would be rejected, because H is y.x and contains a dot

and,

> Set-Cookie from request-host x.foo.com for Domain=.foo.com would be accepted.

So, it seems like a Cookie domain would require at least two dots if it were basing its name on the domain name.  However, the aspnet authentication cookie isn't doing this, so that's why it only requires one dot.

Comment: interesting .. but i still didn't understand all of it. Firstly, I totally understand what a FQDN is and that that they always end with a dot (the ROOT of all the internet) and therefore, having one at the start means there's room for pre-domains (subdomains, sub-subdomains, etc). BUT .. the ASP.NET cookie has _another_ property called Domain (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiedomain.aspx). So are you sure that you are not talking about THAT property, instead?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, No, I'm  not sure.  I posted the link to the documentation, but I didn't spend the time to read it exhaustively.  You can check it out and make your own interpretation.  If you see that I am mistaken, please explain

Comment: The question is about cookie name, not domain name.

Answer (score 11):

The cookie in the same is completely optional and simply reduces the likelihood that you'll overwrite a different cookie that might be set by your code.  The two-dot requirement is related exclusively to the domain name.

Comment: Note also that you can change the cookie name. In cases where you have multiple ASP.NET applications running on the same domain, you actually would want to do this as each app would try and reuse the same cookie.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since OP was asking about `name` and not `domain`. I verified and clarified the answer, and cited the source from Msft. Thank you Anonymous Coward! And for the record, I have successfully used "test" as  the `name` value, proving to myself that the leading period is not required.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary - Please consider posting [your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5902759) as a new answer instead.

Comment: The fact that I made an edit as opposed to posting an answer shows that I already considered this and decided "nope." Not in it for the points; just wanted to update the BOK and cite source for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The leading dot character is necessary. This is necessary because the **HTTP specification demands that a cookies domain property must contain at least two dots**.

This leads to an inconvinience if during development you want to share cookies between http://site1.localhost/  and http://site2.localhost/. To overcome this you can map site1.localhost.dev and site2.localhost.dev to 127.0.0.1 in you host file and then set the domain to **.localhost.dev**

Hope this helps...

Comment: I guess he means the cookie name, not a domain name.

Comment: can you please provide a link/proof of this HTTP spec requirement and why this is? As in .. why did the specification say _contain two dots_. Lastly .. where's the second dot? I only see one (at the start).

Comment: +1, but @sajoshi, please check my answer, because I think you may have missed something.

Comment: are you sure the cookies _domain_ is the same as the cookies _name_? If you read my comments to @smartcaveman 's reply, i'm suggesting that the cookie domain is a *seperate* property on the cookie class. NOT the _name_ property.

Comment: The question is about cookie name, not domain name.