# Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?

If yes, How?

The problem which I've got is that when I have two web applications are deployed in the same domain then when anyone is logged in then the second one will be automatically logged out because they use the same Authentication's cookie name.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631617/how-do-i-customize-the-forms-authentication-cookie-name

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can adjust it in your web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".CookieName" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: For anyone who is wondering at this point, the default cookie name is ".ASPXAUTH"

Comment: What's the difference between .CookieName and .ASPXAUTH?

Comment: @BobSwager The former is a few characters longer.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can specify the cookie name in `web.config` on `forms` element under `authentication` element.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="RoleBasedAuthenticationCookiename" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```