# MVC3 FormsAuthenticationTicket Cookie name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, forms-authentication

> Possible Duplicate:
>   [Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name)

I have multiple MVC3 sites that create FormsAuthentication tickets and store them in cookies.

Login:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), true, String.Empty);
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
```

In Application_AuthenticateRequest:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

Surely this will cause issues if multiple sites are saving to the same cookie?
Is there any harm in having a different cookie name for each app or is there another recommended way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only cause issues if those multiple sites are on the same domain.

You can set the cookie name in the web.config - see [Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name)