# Losing the session in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I developed a website and configured in IIS in the name(abc) and then I copied the same website to another directory and that also configured in IIS with different name(def).

Both the application are working good.

Now, I am opening the abc application(abs/default.aspx) and then in another tab I'm opening def application(def/default.aspx). In this case when I login the second(def) app in the second tab , the first(abc) app is losing the session and then logs out automatically.

Please explain the problem and give me the solution.

Comment: Please use different browser or use tabs in private or incognito mode. Might be both of your hosted application using same cookie for user login.

Answer (score 0):

They probably have the same [`<machinekey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx) configured, or they are [overwriting each other's cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name).

Give each site unique values for keys and cookie names.