# ASP.NET IIS Isolate sessions per website pool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm currently experiencing an issue were I have two app pools on a IIS server, they are two different sites, one running ASP.NET MVC 4.5 and the other ASP.NET Web Forms and are using the default authentication method. They store users on different databases. Right now when I log in on one site and I have the other open on another tab it closes the other session. How can I fix this?

Currently authentication is set for individual accounts. Authentication for each system is completely separated.

Comment: See if both applications are use same cookie name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name

Comment: solved the problem?

Comment: @gpaoli so far I haven't tried it yet, hopefully tomorrow I will get to fix that