# ASP.NET cookie wrongly shared between two sites

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have two ASP.NET websites running in IIS Express as `localhost` with different ports.  I am using `FormsAuthentication` to remember logins through cookies.  However, when I login or logout of one site, it affects the other site, so they seem to share the same cookie.

Is this a common problem, or can I tweak something to avoid this?

Comment: cookies aren't isolated to a given port. See [http cookies specific port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the sites having the same cookie name.

You can adjust it in your web.config file:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".CookieName" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" />
</authentication>`

Source:
[Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name)

Answer (score 2):

Are the two sites under the same domain? You may need to specify the cookie path.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiepath(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that changing the cookie name is not preventing the cookie from being sent to the wrong application.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem as cookies are assigned to host names. You should give different names to AUTH cookies to your sites. Check out how to do that: [Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661943/can-i-change-the-formsauthentication-cookie-name).

Answer (score 0):

http cookies are not isolated to a given port.  [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

browsers will send cookies based on the domain and not take port into consideration.

> For historical reasons, cookies contain a number of security and
>   privacy infelicities. For example, a server can indicate that a given
>   cookie is intended for "secure" connections, but the Secure attribute
>   does not provide integrity in the presence of an active network
>   attacker. Similarly, cookies for a given host are shared across all
>   the ports on that host, even though the usual "same-origin policy"
>   used by web browsers isolates content retrieved via different ports.

If you want to restrict that cookie to an app on your same domain you'll need to set the cookie specific to a virtual directory.  Something like cookie.domain='yourdomain/appRootUrl/'.